# Caffe "Unknown solver type : SGD"

Tags: c++, windows, machine-learning, caffe

Build Caffe (latest version, CPU only build) under Windows 10 for use in VS C++ project. So that everything began to work had to trouble. But when creating an instance of the `Solver` class, an error occurs.

```
SolverParameter solverParam;
ReadSolverParamsFromTextFileOrDie("solver.prototxt", &solverParam);
boost::shared_ptr<Solver<float>> solver(SolverRegistry<float>::CreateSolver(solverParam));
```

Output:

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F0601 14:21:42.943118 10832 solver_factory.cpp:29] Check failed: registry.count(type) == 1 (0 vs. 1) Unknown solver type: SGD (known types: )
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

solver.prototxt content:

> ```
> net: "model.prototxt"
> base_lr: 0.02
> lr_policy: "step"
> gamma: 0.5
> stepsize: 500000
> display: 10
> max_iter: 5000
> snapshot: 1000000
> snapshot_prefix: "XORProblem"
> solver_mode: CPU
> test_iter: 1
> test_interval: 2000
> ```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did not define the type of the solver at all.
Try adding

```
type: "SGD"
```

to your `'solver.prototxt'`.

Solver type should by `"SGD"` by default, but there are two ways to define it: one is using [`solver_type: SGD`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L234-L244), and the other is using [`type: "SGD"`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L215-L216). The first option is marked as "deprecated" in the comments, so I guess this gives you trouble.
Try avoiding the default settings by explicitly setting the solver type using a non-deprecated method.

**Update:**
Looking at the windows branch [readme](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows#building-a-shared-library) it seems like there is an open issue with compiling shared library under windows, specifically with the solvers.
I believe the issue you are experiencing is related to that issue.

Comment: With the addition of `type "SGD"` nothing has changed.

Comment: @D.Stark are you sure your built went smoothly? have you run all tests? It seems like no solvers were registered by caffe.

Comment: No, i'm not sure

Comment: @D.Stark `make test` and then `make runtest` (or something like that)

Comment: Do you mean tests that are run after building the library? Before the building, I specified RUN_TESTS=1 in build_win.cmd. All tests were successfully.

Comment: Same thing as i understood... I built `runtest` from Caffe.sln and it went well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by including "caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.cpp" into "caffe.cpp".

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more?